# Nancy Model Binding

Tags: c#, model-binding, nancy

Hi I'm learning Nancy and I'm trying to bind to a model, but I'm getting the error:

```
Error   8   'NancyFxTutorial.CarModule' does not contain a definition for 'Bind' and no extension method 'Bind' accepting a first argument of type 'NancyFxTutorial.CarModule' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Development\Projects\C#\Web\Nancy\NancyFxTutorial\NancyFxTutorial\CarModule.cs
```

model:

```
public class BrowseCarQuery
{
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
}

public class CarModule : NancyModule
{
    public CarModule()
    {
        Get["/status"] = _ => "Hello World";

        Get["/Car/{id}"] = parameters =>
            {
                int id = parameters.id;
                return Negotiate.WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK).WithModel(id);
            };

        Get["/{make}/{model}"] = parameters =>
        {
            BrowseCarQuery model = new BrowseCarQuery();

            var carQuery = this.Bind<>()

        };
    }
}
```

any clues?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you included an `using` for the correct namespace `Nancy.ModelBinding`? So do you have the `using Nancy.ModelBinding;` in your file?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [Nancy model binding](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Model-binding) methods are defined as [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) on the `NancyModule` class.

And these extension methods can be found in the `Nancy.ModelBinding` namespace.

So you need to `using` the `Nancy.ModelBinding` namespace to access the `Bind()` and `BindTo()` methods.

So add this line to your source file:

```
using Nancy.ModelBinding;
```